# Correct path in open()

Tags: c++, c, file-io, file-descriptor

I'm trying to open a file using `open()` but I'm having a problem with the path. It seems like if the path starts with a forward-slash `/`, it wont find the file, for example if path was `/index.html` then it wont open, if it was `index.html` then it works fine.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't want to parse the path because there might be several forward-slashes like in `///index.html`

```
int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
```

Comment: If a path starts with a `/` it just refers to the root directory... you should explain better what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, the `/` is a forward slash, *not* a backslash.

Comment: If it does not open it must show some messages. What are those?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: never heard that the `open()` gives any error message (why should it be? it's a syscall), if anything he should check `errno`.

Comment: There should be something in `/var/log/{messages,syslog}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the path starts with a slash `/` (a [backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) looks like `\`) the path is absolute and starts at the root of the file system. If it doesn't start with a slash, it is a relative path. It is unclear what you want to do but it seems you might need to remove leading slashes if you want the path to be relative.